# Yii 2 (basic) .htaccess and routing wrong

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii

I'm using Yii 2 (basic) and when i tried to route any content and received problems.

So, I want to remove web/index.php in my url.

```
In my root put .htaccess:
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
```

In my /web folder put 
    RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule . index.php
```

So, when i haven't certain controller, redirects into index.php

The problem is that all controllers are redirected into default controller.

Here is my console.php

```
'urlManager' => [
         'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
         'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
         'showScriptName' => false,

         'rules' => [
                     'dashboard'=>  'site/login',
                     '/' =>'site/index'
   ]
      ],
```